# Use Own VPN Server on Google Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, vpn, google-chrome-extensions, ipsec, softether

I'm looking a way to connect Internet through my VPN server while browsing from Google Chrome Browser. I though best way is use an extension but I couldn't find any extension that let me enter my own VPN information. All extensions have their own servers and I can connect their servers, not mine.

I already added my VPN server (L2TP/IPsec) to Windows 10 with using its own built-in VPN module. But when I connect with it, my whole connections are using the VPN. I don't want that. Does anyone know a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

That’s easy:

- Don’t redirect all traffic to the VPN, only the VPN subnet (“Split Tunneling”)<sup>1</sup>
- Run a HTTP proxy server (like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)) on the VPN subnet
- Use something like FoxyProxy to make only Chrome use the proxy<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1</sup>: Disable “use default gateway on remote network” on the VPN connection’s advanced IPv4 TCP/IP settings.

<sup>2</sup>: Because Chrome by itself can only use the system-wide proxy settings but you don’t want to change these, you need an extension to do this.

Comment: Ok I disabled “Use default gateway on remote network”. Now when I connect to the Internet while I connected VPN, it doesn't use VPN. Also I added FoxyProxy extension to Chrome. It asks proxy server and port, so I believe I should "run a HTTP proxy server on the VPN subnet" to get these information, can you guide me to that?

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not very familiar with SoftEther. A default installation of Squid would generally be sufficient, but you may have to create a virtual network adapter or something to make it available directly on the VPN subnet.